# How to solving PHP Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Tags: php

> PHP Warning:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
> in
> \HP3-WINC2-SMB1.HOSTINGP3.LOCAL\DOMAINSW\708\2512708\user\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\updraftplus\options.php
> on line 155
>
> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
> \HP3-WINC2-SMB1.HOSTINGP3.LOCAL\DOMAINSW\708\2512708\user\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\updraftplus\options.php
> on line 156

Having a problem solving this bug. Any ideas of what to do? It slowing my work incredibly, right now. Thank you

I updated for: It's a line 155

```
    $services_to_register = array_keys($updraftplus->(!empty backup_methods));
```

Comment: clearly `$updraftplus->backup_methods` is not correctly dimensioned at the point when you call `array_keys` so test using `isset()` or `!empty()`

Comment: Thanks for helping. It still showing an error. PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in \\HP3-WINC2-SMB1.HOSTINGP3.LOCAL\DOMAINSW\708\2512708\user\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\updraftplus\options.php on line 155

Comment: if you have made changes can you add the actual code to the question ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misinterpreted the use of `!empty` - I actually meant that you need to test the contents of the `$updraftplus->backup_methods` variable before entering the next piece of code.

```
if( !empty( $updraftplus->backup_methods ) ){

    $services_to_register = array_keys($updraftplus->backup_methods);
    foreach ($services_to_register as $service) {
        register_setting('updraft-options-group', 'updraft_'.$service);
        // We have to add the filter manually in order to get the second parameter passed through (register_setting() only registers with one parameter)
        add_filter('sanitize_option_updraft_'.$service, array($updraftplus, 'storage_options_filter'), 10, 2);
        
        
        //... presumably other PHP code
    }
}
```